# Practical Kabbalah consequences

Tags: mysticism-kabbalah, story-identification, arizal, practical-kabbalah

I remember hearing that there was a rabbi that used practical kabbalah with his disciples to fight SM' + LL', but I cannot remember his name.

Arizal has prohibited it, right?
I remember that he gave names of some rabbanim who used it and made idol worship with practical kaballah, in that list includes the name of the rabbi of this history.

He grouped i think 4 disciples, then he made some meditations, so Elyahu appeared to him and said it wouldn't be possible, because SM'+LI' were too strong, but the rabbi was to give his life for Hashem, so Elyahu gave him some instructions, than after he made the things Elyahu said, angels appeared to him to give more complex instructions, all of them saying that he wouldn't succed. In the end, he gave some spices to SM', so it was considered as avora zarah, just one disciple survived to tell the history.

I would like to remember the name of this rabbi, so i could read the history again

Comment: sm = Samael? ll = Lilit?

Comment: @rikitikitembo I'd assume so

Comment: Yes @rikitikitembo

Comment: if you would kindly edit the question to include that information it would improve your question

Comment: i improved the number of information, thanks if someone could find

Comment: Perhaps try Rabbi Yosef Della Reina, ca. 1418-1472. Hatzlacha

Comment: EXACTLY!!!! RABBI YOSEF DELLA REINA!

Comment: Your pronouns are confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rabbi was: Rabbi Yosef Della Reina.
ca. 1418-1472. Hatzlacha

Comment: Do you have a source?

Comment: This answer could be improved by telling us how you know this to be true.

Comment: I found the answer because someone answered above in my on question, and, after searching by this name, found the same history i was talking about, what i read

Answer (score 6):

From the [Encyclopedia.com entry](https://www.encyclopedia.com/religion/encyclopedias-almanacs-transcripts-and-maps/joseph-della-reina) on Joseph Della Reina:

> JOSEPH DELLA REINA , hero of a kabbalistic legend who attempted to
>   bring an end to Satan's power and thus lead to the redemption. The
>   earliest version of the story, which evolved between the 15th and 17th
>   centuries, is recorded by *Abraham b. Eliezer ha-Levi in his treatise
>   Iggeret Sod ha-Ge'ullah, written in Jerusalem in 1519. The author used
>   terms current only in kabbalistic literature of the period of the
>   expulsion from Spain (1492). The story is very short and dwells more
>   on a detailed description of Satan and his hosts than on the hero and
>   his deeds. However, its salient feature is Joseph's burning of incense
>   before Satan; this, being tantamount to idolatry, caused Joseph's
>   failure and undoing.

**Ibid:**

> The story of Joseph was known in 16th-century Safed. Moses *Cordovero
>   and Ḥayyim *Vital mention his name in descriptions of the dangers of
>   messianic and magical activity. Ḥayyim Vital also recalls that his
>   teacher Isaac *Luria once recognized Joseph's soul in the body of a
>   black dog, Joseph's punishment for his crime.

The story can be read [here](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/33894).